# Extract Data from Ads Report to Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-ads-api

Hi I am trying to write a script that will extract the data from Google Ads Report (Call Details) or 'call_metrics_call_details_report' to a spreadsheet automatically.
I have been able to extract all the details  successfully - except for the caller phone number. There also does not seem to be a google attribute for this. Can anybody help? Thank you

```
function importCallDetails() {
  var accountId = AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getCustomerId();

  var startDate = "INSERT_START_DATE_HERE";
  var endDate = "INSERT_END_DATE_HERE";

  var query = "SELECT CallStartTime, CallDuration, CallerCountryCallingCode, CampaignName,     CampaignId " + "FROM CALL_METRICS_CALL_DETAILS_REPORT";

  var report = AdsApp.report(query);

  var data = report.rows();

  var spreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/*********/';
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl);
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('PAGE1');

  ss.clearContents();

  report.exportToSheet(ss);
}

  function main() {
  importCallDetails();
}
```

Comment: I assume that Google won't provide the exact caller phone number for privacy reasons.

Comment: I am able to view the customer phone number from within the google ads report, but I am too wondering if this function is blocked to assist in preventing someone from creating scripts for scam purposes